# Cell reference of pandas data frame, filtering based on specific value

Tags: pandas, indexing

I need to get the cell reference (row#, col#) for all the areas in my pandas data frame that contains a value == 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                   'y': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                   'z': [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

Looking to get a final dataframe with two columns: row & col that looks like:

```
  row  col
0  1    1
1  4    1
2  4    2
3  0    3
4  2    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

**This should be much faster than all solutions using `for` loop, `df.stack`, etc. Please see the timings below**:

```
In [145]: import numpy as np

In [146]: res = pd.DataFrame(np.argwhere(df.notnull().values).tolist(), columns=['row', 'col'])

In [147]: res.col = res.col + 1

In [148]: res
Out[148]: 
   row  col
0    0    3
1    1    1
2    2    3
3    4    1
4    4    2
```

#### Timings:

`np.argwhere`:

```
In [149]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.argwhere(df.notnull().values).tolist(), columns=['row', 'col'])
437 µs ± 4.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@sophocles solution using `df.stack`:

```
In [151]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df[df.notna()].stack().index.tolist(),columns=['row','col'])
1.33 ms ± 5.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)  to get a boolean DataFrame back, and [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to remove the `nan` which have been converted to `False`.  Grab the `index` and convert to list so that you can easily convert to DataFrame.

Wrapping that in a [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with correct column names gives you what you need:

```
df.columns=[1,2,3]
pd.DataFrame(df[df.notna()].stack().index.tolist(),columns=['row','col'])
```

---

```
   row  col
0    0    3
1    1    1
2    2    3
3    4    1
4    4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over rows and columns:

```py
res_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['row', 'col'])

for i in range(len(df)):
  for j in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df[df.columns[j]].iloc[i] == 1:
      res_df = res_df.append({'row': i, 'col': j+1}, ignore_index=True)

print(res_df.sort_values(by='col').reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
  row col
0   1   1
1   4   1
2   4   2
3   0   3
4   2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                   'y': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                   'z': [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})

list_indexes = []
for idx in range(len(df.columns)):
    rows = df.index[df.iloc[:, idx] == 1].tolist()
    for row in rows:
        list_indexes.append((row, idx+1))

final = pd.DataFrame(list_indexes, columns=['row', 'column'])
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df.columns=list(range(1,len(df.columns)+1))

   1    2   3
0   NaN NaN 1.0
1   1.0 NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN 1.0
3   NaN NaN NaN
4   1.0 1.0 NaN
```

```
new_df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_0':'row', 'level_1':'col'})[['row', 'col']]

   row  col
0    0    3
1    1    1
2    2    3
3    4    1
4    4    2
```